# get data attribute in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select form like this in a v-for loop:

```
<div class="select">
    <select v-model="shippingMethod">
        <option value="{{shipping.id}}" v-for="shipping in shippingMethods" data-price="{{ shipping.amount}}">{{shipping.description}} - {{shipping.amount / 100}}</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select__arrow"></div>
</div>
```

If I watch my `shippingMethod` model and run a method like this:

```
updateTotal: function(event){
    console.log(this.shippingMethod);
},
```

I can get the new value of the selected option. The issue is I also need the data-price value as well. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Is shipping methods an array? If so, instead of passing the `{{shipping.id}}` as the `value`, you could pass the array index `{{index}}`. Then, in your `updateTotal` method you could access the current option with `this.shippingMethods[this.shippingMethod]`.

The whole thing would look like this:

```
<div class="select">
<select v-model="shippingMethod">
    <option value="{{index}}" v-for="(shipping, index) in shippingMethods" data-price="{{ shipping.amount}}">{{shipping.description}} - {{shipping.amount / 100}}</option>
</select>
    <div class="select__arrow"></div>
</div>


updateTotal: function(event){
    console.log(this.shippingMethods[this.shippingMethod]);
},
```

Comment: Yes this is Vue 1.0 and `shipping` is an array.

Comment: If I do that `shipping.amount` and `shipping.description` doesnt work and console is undefined. 

value looks like this in inspector : `<option value="[object Object]"> - NaN</option>`